# Swift : Filtering NSDate by time intervals

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, nsdate, nscalendar

I have an array with `NSDate()` that the user adds with a `datePicker`, then this dates need to be filtered by current week, current month and year. I have tried using `NSCalendar` but I couldn't make it work. 
I want to group this `NSDates` in different arrays depending on the time interval that they are in.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply use `NSPredicate`:

```
NSArray *arrayOfDates = @[
                    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0],
                    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:100],
                    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:200]
                   ];

NSDate *leftLimit = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:50];
NSDate *rightLimit = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:150];
NSPredicate *dateIntervalPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self > %@ && self < %@", leftLimit, rightLimit];
NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:dateIntervalPredicate];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

Of course, you can wrap it into a function, it's just an example.

Comment: Not actually Swift (nor swift).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, oh, sorry. I missed the tag.